# Wifi Network Adapters not connecting

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, windows-11

I have a laptop with built-in Wi-Fi, as well as a Wi-Fi dongle. Both show up as network adapters but they otherwise don't work. Windows 11 doesn't give me an option to connect to an access point.

If I view the detailed status of the network adapter (Network Connections -> right click adapter -> status -> Details...), it is empty. If I use the diagnose button in the same status window, it detects a problem, attempts to update the driver and still fails. The error it gives is "Windows couldn't automatically bind the IP protocol stack to the network adapter."

This error doesn't occur for my ethernet dongle, nor for Bluetooth tethering.

I tried restarting several times. I tried rolling back a Windows update that happened on the day that it stopped working, but that didn't fix it. The last option is to nuke and reinstall, but I'd like to exhaust my options before trying that.

Hardware details. Built-in adapter: Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168 with drivers - Netwtw04 @ 19.51.15.3 - vwifibus @ 10.0.22000.653 - IntelWifihv04 @ unknown Dongle: TP-Link Wireless USB Adapter with drivers: - rtwlanu @ 1030.38.0712.2019 - vwifibus @ 10.0.22000.653

Comment: What models are the two adapters? What drivers do you use for them?

Comment: Builtin adapter: Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168


with drivers


 - Netwtw04 @ 19.51.15.3
 - vwifibus @ 10.0.22000.653
 - IntelWifihv04 @ unknown


Dongle: TP-Link Wireless USB Adapter


with drivers:


- rtwlanu @ 1030.38.0712.2019
- vwifibus @ 10.0.22000.653

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, head over to Services and make sure the `WLAN Autoconfig` service is started. if not then start it.

Now open a CMD window as administrator and run the following commands:

•   Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults:

```
netsh winsock reset catalog
```

•   Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

```
netsh int ip reset reset.log
```

•   Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

```
netsh advfirewall reset
```

•   Flush DNS resolver cache:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

•   Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

```
ipconfig /registerdns
```

•   Flush routing table (reboot required):

```
route /f
```

Now reboot your computer and try to connect to the WiFi again.